# Change the axes on a radial barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a radial stacked barchart. I have something like this:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill= cut)) +  geom_bar()  + coord_polar()
```

which yields a plot like this:
[image: radial barchart]

However this is very crowded. Is there a way to change the axes so that this barchart is hollow? I would want zero to start not at the center of the circle but, say, 1/3  or 1/2 of the radius from the center. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Perhaps a dummy category with a name of "" and a color of "grey"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `coord_plot` to expand slightly - this puts a small hole in the middle:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill= cut)) +  
    geom_bar()  + 
    coord_polar(expand=TRUE)
```

[image]

Then you can control the y scale expansion (with the argument `expand=...` to `scale_y_continuous(...)`. Unfortunately I think the expansion is symmetrical, i.e. if you add space at the bottom (i.e. in the middle, you also add it at the top (i.e. the outside):

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill= cut)) +  
    geom_bar()  + 
    coord_polar(expand=TRUE) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.5, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: not a bad solution. if necessary I can always cut the outer edges off in a graphics program.

Comment: In ggplot 3.3.5 `coord_polar(expand = TRUE)` yields: `Error in coord_polar(expand = TRUE) : unused argument (expand = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with an axis transformation. What this transformation does is:

- offset the y-axis 0-point by `offset`
- transform the radius with `sqrt` so that the areas of the bars correspond to the values.

I used this to plot histograms of times of the day, the offset makes small values way better visible. Of course circular plots only really make sense for seasonal data, direction data, ...

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

offset=2000
my_trafo_trans <- function() trans_new(
  "my_trafo",
  function(y){
    sign(y)*sqrt(abs(y))+offset^2
  }, 
  function(r){
    r^2+offset^2
  }
  )

ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill= cut)) +  
  geom_bar()  + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1*offset, 15000)) + 
  coord_trans(y = "my_trafo") +
  coord_polar()
```

[image: result of plot command]